# Unable to save forms to the database for inline formsets using form wizard in Django

Tags: python, django, survey, inline-formset, formwizard

I am currently working on building a survey. The parent model 'Person' is linked to a 'Question' model via ManytoMany relationship. Both Question and Person model are linked to an 'Answer' model via foreign key.

Currently, I am having issues using the Form Wizard which consists of two steps: First step is the Person form and the second step is the form consisting of an inline formset linking the Person and Answer model.

On saving the forms to the database in the 'done'  function of the wizard, I seem to be getting the error

'save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'person'

Thanks in advance.

views.py

```
class AnswerWizard(SessionWizardView):

    template_name = 'survey/wizard_form.html'

    def get_template_names(self):
        return 'survey/wizard_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
        context = super(AnswerWizard, self).get_context_data(form=form, 
                         **kwargs)
        return context

    def get_form_initial(self, step):
        return self.initial_dict.get(step, {})

    def get_form(self, step=None, data=None, files=None):
        form = super(AnswerWizard, self).get_form(step, data, files)
        return form


    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        for form in form_list:
                print(form)
                form.save()

        return render_to_response('survey/thanks.html')
```

models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100,
                                      verbose_name="Name",
                                      null=False,
                                      default=None,unique=True
                                      )

    def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse('survey:wizard', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
       return self.name

class Question_free(models.Model):
question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200,
                                 verbose_name="Question name",
                                 null=True,
                                 default=None,
                                )
person = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Answer')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text


class Answer(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question_free)
    answer_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer_text
```

Comment: That's because you ``return`` after the first item in the loop is processed. Indentation is very important in Python. Please don't post code as image next time, post it as text.

Comment: Thanks for that. On making the change, I get the error 'save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'person'.